# Is bioinformatics a on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

Are bioinformatics questions on-topic on this forum?

Or is there a .stackexchange forum more dedicated to bioinformatics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a Stack Exchange site currently dedicated to bioinformatics. Bioinformatics should be on-topic here, since it is computational, and it shares some methods with statistics and machine learning. I think as long as the questions are more about computatjional methods and less about biology, it could work well. A challenge we face as an interdisciplinary community is getting enough experts to contribute both questions and answers when new topics come up. Computational chemistry is on-topic, for instance, but most of those questions have migrated to Chemistry Stack Exchange; you might try looking at Biology Stack Exchange to see if they have a community of bioinformaticians.

Comment: +1 There's a proposal at area51 (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62211/bioinformatics), but it hasn't started yet (we need followers!). In the meantime Biology SE and Computational Science SE seem to be the closest options.

Answer (score 1):

We accept bioinformatics questions in BiologySE given that they are not really about coding. See [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioinformatics). For coding stackoverflow would be the appropriate site.

You may also want to have a look at [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/) (which is modeled on SE 1.0 but not a part of stackexchange)